# Trying to get text for a "game" where it should refresh/randomize HP and DMG values, but is not

Tags: python, object

Really new to Python and I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to get HP and DMG to randomize when it's called when the button I've created is clicked.

Here's currently what I have:

```
# find your fav character images and pass it here
Char1 = Character('Snart.png','CAPTAIN COLD',DISPLAYSURF,(100,300),200)
Char2 = Character('Flash.png','FLASH',DISPLAYSURF,(700,300),200)

def displayButtons(bList):
    for x in bList:
    x.display()    

def main():

    B1.active = True
    clickCount = 1
    B2.active = False

    while True:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            ## MOUSE EVENTS
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if B1.clicked(mouse):
                    B1.highlight = True
                    print("Hello") ## Just to see if it actually get's pressed
                    clickCount = 2
                elif B2.clicked(mouse):
                    B2.highlight = True
                    print("Bye") ## Just to see if it actually get's pressed
                    clickCount = 1

            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if B1.clicked(mouse):
                    Char1.Randomize() ## Randomize the HP DMG
                    B1.highlight = False
                    B1.active = False
                    B2.active = True
                elif B2.clicked(mouse):
                    Char2.Randomize() ## Randomize the HP DMG
                    B2.highlight = False
                    B2.active = False
                    B1.active = True

        Char1.display()
        Char2.display() 
        displayButtons(BUTTONLIST)  
        pygame.display.update()
main()
```

And for the class that it's creating:

```
class Character(object):

def __init__(self, imagefile,charname,surf,pos,scalesize):
    self.SURF = surf
    self.POS = pos
    self.IMAGESURF = pygame.image.load(imagefile)
    self.IMAGESURF = pygame.transform.scale(self.IMAGESURF,  (scalesize,scalesize))

    self.HP = (0, 300) # should range from (0 - 300) ## randint: return a random integer(start,stop)
    self.DMG = (0, 100) # should range from (0 - 100)

    self.GameFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Sylfaen", 50)
    # this text has a black background. Can you make it transparent ?. DONE
    self.NAME = self.GameFont.render(charname, True,(255,255,255),None) 
    self.Randomize()
    self.__drawText()
    self.__displayText()




# complete this function
# this function should randomize HP, DMG and should display on the screen
# this function should be called on a button press
    def Randomize(self):
        #pass
        self.HP = randint(0, 300)
        self.DMG = randint(0, 300)


## DON'T UNCOMMENT UNLESS YOU WANT IT TO RANDOMLY GENERATE NON-STOP
##        self.HPText = self.GameFont.render('HP : ' +str(self.HPrand), True,(255,255,255),None)
##        self.DMGText = self.GameFont.render('DMG: ' +str(self.DMGrand), True,(255,255,255),None)

    def __displayText(self):
        self.SURF.blit(self.HPText,(self.POS[0]+200,self.POS[1]+50))
        self.SURF.blit(self.DMGText,(self.POS[0]+200,self.POS[1]+150))

        self.SURF.blit(self.NAME,(self.POS[0]+20,self.POS[1]-100))


# fix the error in this function, DONE
    def __drawText(self):
        # this text has a black background. Can you make it transparent ?.
        self.HPText = self.GameFont.render('HP : ' +str(self.HP), True,(255,255,255),None)
        self.DMGText = self.GameFont.render('DMG: ' +str(self.DMG), True,(255,255,255),None)


# fix the errors in this function, DONE
    def display(self):
        self.Randomize()
        self.__displayText()
        self.SURF.blit(self.IMAGESURF,self.POS)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you randomize the `HP` and `DMG` values, you need to re-render the text values for each of them. You have a function to do that, named `__drawText`, but you're not calling it when the button is pressed. This is why you keep drawing the old values even after `Randomize` has been called.

I'm not sure exactly how you want your class to work, but perhaps `__drawText` should be called from `Randomize`? You can't rely upon the external code that that runs `Randomize` to also call `__drawText` since you've given it a name starting with two underscores (which invokes Python's name mangling system). If it's supposed to be part of the class API, you certainly don't want to be doing that. External code *can* still call `__drawText`, but only by manually doing the mangling (and calling e.g. `Char1._Character__drawText`).

One final thing, which is unrelated to your current issues. Your variables are being named in a way that is a bit unusual for Python code. The more usual Python style is to use `lowercase_with_underscores` names for most variables and functions (including methods), and reserve `TitleCase` names for classes. `ALL_CAPS` is used occasionally for variables that are notionally constant, but the regular variable style is also pretty common even for constants (e.g. `math.pi`).

Using a different naming convention doesn't make your code wrong, but it may be harder for other programmers to follow than if you followed the standard conventions. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the style used for the official Python interpreter. A lot of other Python code follows that guide (with perhaps a little more leeway given on line lengths). Google also has a [Python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html), which is (as far as I can tell) pretty much compatible with PEP 8.